# Анонимное закрытие вопроса

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Задал я такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1376224/221228). Сегодня его закрыли. Но самое интересное, что в плашке закрытия нет авторов закрытия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычно же писалось. Даже если вопрос закрывал Дух или обладатель золотого знака. Что сейчас пошло не так?

Comment: странно, у меня отображаются

Comment: @Grundy может потому, что вы модератор? В анонимной вкладке у меня тоже ничего не видно

Comment: у меня тоже видно

Comment: Может это такое поведение для автора вопроса?

Comment: Возможно (чего-то опасаются? и на всякий случай не хотят нагнетать), у меня тоже видны имена героев

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего так сделано именно для автора закрытого вопроса в качестве минимизации вероятности «ответочек» в сторону закрывших вопрос. У меня отображается в таком виде:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но даже не будучи залогиненым, можно увидеть список закрывших вопрос через [временную шкалу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1376224/timeline).

Есть похожий вопрос на MSE и [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340341/339911).

Comment: Тогда непонятно к чему относится надпись "Отображается автору вопроса...". Похоже и автору, и незалогиненным отображается примерно одно и то же, только у последних вместо "Редактировать вопрос" идет кнопка "Улучшить вопрос".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight может поведение (код) поменяли, а коммент остался. Классика.